# Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'String.SubSequence' (aka 'Substring') and 'String'

Tags: swift, variables, character

I'm using

```
var chars = Array(string.hasPrefix("#") ? string.characters.dropFirst() : string.characters)
```

Got this Error

> "Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'String.SubSequence' (aka 'Substring') and 'String'"

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dropFirst()` returns a `Substring` from your string, and the complier is complaining that you return a different `Substring` type if true and `String` type when false

Just cast the `Substring` to `String` like `String(yourSubString)` and it should work

```
var chars = Array(string.hasPrefix("#") ? String(string.characters.dropFirst()) : string.characters)
```

Answer (score 1):

The second and third operands of the ternary `?:` operator must be of the same type. `dropFirst` returns a `Substring`, whereas `characters` is a `String`, hence causing the error.

Another thing to note is that you don't need `.characters` since Swift 4.

Your whole expression can be rearranged to:

```
var chars = string.hasPrefix("#") ? Array(string.dropFirst()) : Array(string)
```

This way, the last two operands are both of type `[Character]`, making the error go away.